# Is it possible to re-identify a particular electron? are there identity conditions for electrons?

Tags: electrons, soft-question

I think that being able to formulate a clear identity criterion for the objects it deals with is important for any theory.

For example, set theory starts by the extensionality axiom telling that

```
  set A is identical to set B iff A and B have exactly the same elements.
```

[ In the same way, arithmetics says that number *a* and number *b* are equal (i.e. are exactly the same number) iff

```
                               a-b = 0 ]
```

Consequently, I'm led to ask the question: what are the identity conditions for electrons?

In which case and under which conditions (sufficient and necessary) can I say that this electron *e2* that I observe now is the same electron as electron *e1* I observed previously?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles “Identical particles, also called indistinguishable or indiscernible particles, are particles that cannot be distinguished from one another, even in principle.”

Comment: "Hey, electron 27c, come over here, I wanna have a talk with you."

Comment: `a-b = 0` is a circular definition of equality since it uses the equality relation in its definition.

Comment: Didn't Feynman once says "there is only one electron in the universe"?.

Comment: Sure, you connect a debugger to our Matrix and look at their memory addresses

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All electrons, like all elementary particles, are completely [identical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles) and thus indistinguishable. They can be in different quantum *states*, but you cannot be sure which electron is in which state.

The reason that all electrons are identical is that they are all quanta of *one* [quantum field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory) describing electrons and positrons that extends throughout the universe. There is just one quantum field for each kind of elementary particle/antiparticle. Physics is not about the $10^{80}$ particles in (the observable part of) our universe; it is about the 17 (by one way of counting, in today’s Standard Model) quantum fields in our universe.

The identicality of fermions such as electrons is the basis for the [Pauli exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle). Without it, chemistry and biology as we know them would not be possible because atoms would have all of their electrons in the ground state. The identicality of bosons such as photons is the basis for technology such as lasers.

Comment: I have absolutely no knowledge of physics, but in popular presentations of this subject, it is said that some atoms have, say, 3 electrons turning around the nucleus. Being given that electrons are indistinguishable, how is it possible to count them?

Comment: If you have identical twins, you may not be able to tell them apart but you can tell that there are two of them. If you close your eyes, you can’t know whether they changed places while you had your eyes shut.

Comment: OK, so electrons are identical " qualitatively" but are nevertheless numerically diffferent. My question was specifically : how to determine that two ( supposedly two) electrons are not numerically identical.

Comment: Now you tell me! I guess I can stop looking for a paintbrush fine enough to make them different colors...

Comment: By “numerically different” I assume you mean “in a different state”. They can have different energies, for example.

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames :  It makes sense to say that I have three dollars in my bank account.  It makes sense to say I've just withdrawn one of those dollars.  It does not follow that the question "Which of the three dollars did you withdraw?" has to make any sense.

Comment: By "numerical " identity, I mean that object A is the same object as object B ( they are one and the same object, they count as 1). By " qualitative" identity I mean : A and B, though being 2 disntinct objects, have the same properties. - My question was : how to tell whether two electrons are numerically identical? in case they are not, how to tell they are not numerically identical?

Comment: Thanks for theses answers.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for catching my embarrassing typo! I’ve fixed it.

Comment: Identical particles, whether fermions or bosons, are not numerically identical by your own definition because they do not “count as 1”. Two electrons, being fermions, cannot be in the same state so they have different spin directions, or different energies, or different positions, or whatever. As I previously explained, it is easy to tell that there are two, not one. But you can’t say which one is in which state.

Comment: @WillO The dollar metaphor is great, if you ignore serial numbers ;-). I suggest to make it silver dollars.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica the dollars in your bank account do not have serial numbers. The banknote you got when withdrawing a dollar has a serial number, but you can not predict, which serial number it will have, and you could further say, your withdrawal assigned a serial number to the dollar, which it didn’t have before. When you used a different ATM, the same dollar had a different serial number. This analogy is really great.

Comment: I think indistinguishable particles mean they do not have anything else to be distinguished with other than position, speed, etc. If I study two electrons in a system, can I say the electron at position x has speed v_x, and the electron at position y has speed v_y? I would say yes. There is no problem for that. After 1ps, can I say the electron that was at position x is now in position x+dx? I would say yes. If the one at position y was far away, can I say the one now at x+dx was not the electron that was at y? I would say yes. The bank $ analogy may be great but it does not reflect reality.

Comment: @verdelite At time 0 you observe two electrons with position-momentum states $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$.  At time 1 a wizard may or may not use magic to swap the positions and momenta of the two electrons.  At time 2, there is no measurement you can make that will tell you whether the wizard did that.  That's what we mean by "electrons are indistinguishable".  (By contrast, suppose the objects with states $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ were an atom of carbon-12 and an atom of carbon-13; then you _could_ tell.)

Comment: @zwol here comes the question, why would the wizard swap a C-12 and another C-12 (some times) but will never swap a C-12 and a C-13? Also in QM it is not prevented that a C-12 and another C-12 may be swapped with speed faster than light. That is something I am not comfortable with QM, or at least with its Copenhagen Interpretation. Let's stop here before the comments being labeled.

Comment: This assumes you are using the quantum field model of course.

Comment: @Holger in other words, a dollar bill _is_ not a dollar, it _represents_ a dollar. I suppose you could say indistinguishable particles are the world's most fungible commodity.

Answer (score 2):

Subatomic particles are in principle indistinguishable. The quantum mechanical mathematics used to describe them in interactions explicitly contains that fundamental indistinguishability and provides a testable and falsifiable account of reality at the quantum level. That account is in stunningly accurate agreement with experiment; examples of such results can be found in Richard Feynman's popular book about *QED* (quantum electrodynamics).

This illustrates at least one fundamental difference between philosophy and physics.

Comment: *"provides a testable and falsifiable account of reality [...] is in stunningly accurate agreement with experiment."* You should give at least the *names* of some of these tests or this is a bare assertion. And it's not like there is any lack of choices: nuclear structure, atomic structure, the band theory of solid-state physics, white-dwarf and neutroin star mass ranges, experimental creation of BECs, etc ...

Comment: The reason I did not was I felt the OP did not have a science background, and that furnishing QED calculation results agreeing with experiment to 8-place accuracy would be of no use to him. Will edit. -NN

Comment: Thanks for the reference @nielsnielsen . OP's knowledge/background is normally not important, since it's all about the question and the completeness of the answers which allow others to learn more and investigate further the topics being covered.